# Why is my original 2D array being modified in the following code

Tags: python

Im trying to solve a coding problem where i have to generate some matrices, im  new to python and i cant figure out why my matrix keeps getting changed to the latest matrix being generated. Here's the code i have so far:

```
def mirrorHorizontal(m):
    l = list(m)
    matrix_len = len(l)
    for x in range(0,matrix_len):
        temp = l[x][matrix_len-1]
        l[x][matrix_len-1] = l[x][0]
        l[x][0] = temp
    return l

def mirrorVertical(m):
    l = list(m)
    matrix_len = len(l)
    for x in range(0,matrix_len):
        temp = l[0][x]
        l[0][x] = l[matrix_len-1][x] 
        l[matrix_len-1][x] = temp
    return l


def rotateMatrix(m):
    l = list(m)
    matrix_len = len(l)
    rotated_matrix = []
    for x in range(0,matrix_len):
        rotated_row = []
        for y in range(0, matrix_len):
            rotated_row.append([(matrix_len-1) -y][y])
        rotated_matrix.append(rotated_row)
    return rotated_matrix


# Complete the formingMagicSquare function below.
def formingMagicSquare(s):
    all_matrices = []
    base_matrix = [[8,3,4],[1,5,9],[6,7,2]]
    all_matrices.append(base_matrix)
    print("all matrices after first append",all_matrices)

    base_h_mirror = list(mirrorHorizontal(base_matrix))
    print("horizontal_mirror",base_h_mirror)
    all_matrices.append(base_h_mirror)
    print("all matrices after first h  mirror append",all_matrices)

    base_v_mirror = list(mirrorVertical(base_matrix))
    print("vertical_mirror",base_v_mirror)
    all_matrices.append(base_v_mirror)
    print("all matrices after first v mirror append",all_matrices)


    #Same as vertical mirror of horizontal mirror
    base_v_h_mirror = list(mirrorHorizontal(base_v_mirror))

    all_matrices.append(base_h_mirror)
    print("h_mirror added",all_matrices)

    all_matrices.append(base_v_mirror)
    print("h_mirror added",all_matrices)

    all_matrices.append(base_v_h_mirror)
    print("base_v_h_mirror added",all_matrices)

    print("mirrored matrices= ",all_matrices)

    matrix_len = len(all_matrices)
    for x in range(0,matrix_len):
        all_matrices.append(rotateMatrix(all_matrices[x]))

    print(all_matrices)

formingMagicSquare()
```

The output , if you run it is something like:

```
all matrices after first append [[[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 2]]]

horizontal_mirror [[4, 3, 8], [9, 5, 1], [2, 7, 6]]

all matrices after first h  mirror append
 [
[[4, 3, 8], [9, 5, 1], [2, 7, 6]],
 [[4, 3, 8], [9, 5, 1], [2, 7, 6]]
]
vertical_mirror [[2, 7, 6], [9, 5, 1], [4, 3, 8]]

all matrices after first v mirror append
 [[[2, 7, 6], [9, 5, 1], [4, 3, 8]], 
[[2, 7, 6], [9, 5, 1], [4, 3, 8]],
 [[2, 7, 6], [9, 5, 1], [4, 3, 8]]]

h_mirror added [[[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]]]
h_mirror added [[[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]]]
base_v_h_mirror added [[[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]]]
mirrored matrices=  [[[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]], [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]]]
```

Why is my matrix being populated with the same matrix again and again? I converted the list in the functions i used by slicing it `[:]`

Comment: Without picking through the code; `[:]` is a _shallow_ copy

Comment: Please provide a [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It is very hard to read through all your code. And provide an information where exactly the error oocurs.

Comment: @UliSotschok Please go through the above code it is literally the most minimal code example i could provide , and theres no error, i am getting unexpected behaviour, described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also related to [mutable and immutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types). You are dealing with lists of lists, which are lists of mutables. So the inner lists are passed by reference, even if you use `[:]` which makes a *shallow copy*: a copy of the container, but holding references to the inner object if they are mutables.
That's why, when you change the inner lists, you are changing the *same* inner lists each time. They are all references to the same lists.

Have a look at the [copy docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) to more details about shallow copies and deep copies. This will also give you a solution: use a deep copy.

In each function, replace:

```
l = list(m)
```

with:

```
l = copy.deepcopy(m)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tried replacing `[:]` with `list()` and it didn't work, `copy.deepcopy()` does the trick.